# How to set event on custom form property in Outlook VBA?

Tags: vba, forms, events, outlook

In my custom appointment-form I have a modified form page (P.2) where the second combobox (the project activity) needs to be re-populated when the value in the first combobox (the project name) is changed.

I want to achieve this by setting a Change-event on the first combobox.

Where did I mess up? Is there a better alternative?

I tried two methods:

**1. CustomPropertyChange Event handler in ThisOutlookSession**
As per [this manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.custompropertychange) I applied a CustomPropertyChange event handler:

```
Private WithEvents objInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors
Private WithEvents objAppointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objInspectors = Application.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub objInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    If Inspector.CurrentItem.Class = olAppointment Then
       Set objAppointment = Inspector.CurrentItem
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub objAppointment_Open(Cancel As Boolean)
' This procedure triggers normally
    With objAppointment
          .Recipients.ResolveAll
          .GetInspector.SetCurrentFormPage "P.2"
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub objAppointment_CustomPropertyChange(ByVal myPropName)
' After adding this procedure, the error (see below) appears
    MsgBox myPropName
End Sub
```

Now, when I startup Outlook the following error appears and points to the line `Private Sub Private Sub objAppointment_CustomPropertyChange`:

> Compile error: Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name

The event objAppointment_Open however does work and is in accordance to the same manual.

**2. Custom form script**
The second method I tried is through the custom form script (Appointment item > Developer tab > Design This Form > View Code):

```
Sub Item_CustomPropertyChange(ByVal Name)
    MsgBox "The " & Name & " custom property changed."
End Sub
```

There is no error, but no message box appears. After some research I found that the custom form script is disabled by default. I enabled it according to [this manual](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Custom-form-script-is-now-disabled-by-default-bd8ea308-733f-4728-bfcc-d7cce0120e94).
After this, still no response.
Besides this, it is rather strange that when I add another event handler (for instance Item_Open) to the custom script, and then close and reopen the editor, this is what I see:

```
Sub Item_CustomPropertyChange(ByVal Name)
    MsgBox "The " & Name & " custom property changed."
End Sub ??@___??
___?_????????____??
___?_??????__??????????`_????????___
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer by solving the issue in the first method above (CustomPropertyChange Event handler in ThisOutlookSession). The AppointmentItem-object resulting from Inspector.CurrentItem is in read-only ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.currentitem)). I highly suspect that this is the issue since it turned out that the events Open and Read did work and the events Write and CustomPropertyChange did not.

I have now changed my code to:

```
Public WithEvents myItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
    ' Confirm if it actually is an appointment:
    If Item.Class <> olAppointment Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Initiate event handlers
    Set myItem = Item
End Sub
Private Sub myItem_Open(Cancel As Boolean)
    Debug.Print "myItem_Open triggered"
End Sub
Private Sub myItem_CustomPropertyChange(ByVal Name As String)
    Select Case Name
        Case "cfProjectName" 'Field name of custom property
            Debug.Print "Case cfProjectName"
            ' Performing actions based on first combobox change here
        Case "cfCustomActivityName" 'Field name of custom property
            Debug.Print "Case cfCustomActivityName"
            ' Performing actions based on second combobox change here
        Case Else
    End Select
End Sub
```

I still don’t know what the issue is with the second method (Custom form script). However, this was already not the preferred method since I had to make registry changes.